# Meteor autoform unresponsive script warning

Tags: performance, meteor

I am using aldeed:autoform in my Meteor project for a bigger form. The form contains several normal fields and an array field. Each array item has about 5 fields. When the array has only a few entries everything is working fine. But if the number of array items increases the page gets slower (if there are more than 10 array items, clicking on the "plus" symbol to add an item already takes 1-2sec). 
The submitting also takes a long time. With 15 array items it takes more than 30s (and takes all CPU during that time).
The main problem is that the script gets unresponsive during those 30s and the browser raises a warning asking the user to stop the script (which kills meteor).
But an array with 15 items is a pretty common usecase.
Are there ways to increase the performance of autoform? (maybe making some features not responsive?) How could the Browser Warning be avoided?

I am using the default afArrayField.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to raise an issue on GitHub

Comment: I have the same problem with autoform and thinking about making my own form